# Not operand in Python

Tags: python, boolean

I am trying to display an error message only when the input is not a primary color. However, the error message displays for the first and second color regardless of the input.

```
color1 = input("Enter your first color (red, blue, yellow):").lower()
color2 = input("Enter your second color (red, blue, yellow):").lower()

    if (color1 == "red" and color2 == "blue") or (color1 == "blue" and color2 == "red"):
        print("Your result is purple")
    elif (color1 == "red" and color2 == "yellow") or (color1 == "yellow" and color2 == "red"):
        print("Your result is orange")
    elif (color1 == "blue" and color2 == "yellow") or (color1 == "yellow" and color2 == "blue"):
        print("Your result is green")

    if color1 not in ["red" "blue" or "yellow"]:
        print("Error: The first color you entered is invalid.")
    elif color2 not in ["red" "blue" or "yellow"]:
        print("Error: The second color you entered is invalid.")
    elif color1 == color2:
        print("Error: The two colors you entered are the same.")
```

I have used the not in [] and have tried Boolean (color1 = False)

Comment: `if color1 not in ["red", "blue", "yellow"]`…

Comment: Getting an answer would be easier if you ask a question, and also show a simpler  snippet (proportionately simple to the question asked).

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> if color1 not in ["red" "blue" or "yellow"]:
> ```

Two string literals next to one another get concatenated, so this is `["redblue" or "yellow"]`, and Python is not a logic language so using a boolean combinator (and/or) will just return one of the operands depending on the operation, `or` returns the first truthy parameter and non-empty strings are truthy.

So what you wrote is essentiall just

```
if color1 not in ["redblue"]
```

What you want is test if `color1` is in [a list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) e.g.

```
if color1 not in ["red", "blue", "yellow"]:
```

Comment: I see my mistake, thanks. But I'm still outputting the error message regardless of input.

Answer (score 0):

Your lists should be `["red", "blue", "yellow"]`.

The reason you don't get a syntax error is that `"red" "blue"` is implicitly joined into the single string `"redblue"` at compile time, and the resulting expression `"redblue" or "yellow"` evaluates to `"redblue"` at runtime. If you enter `redblue` for the first color, you'll see that your existing code accepts it.